# Only sometimes get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting uitabviewcontroller viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create and set VCs for my tab view controller. There is a next button in each VC that either opens the next tab or loads a new set of tabs when it reaches the end. Inside both `Type1.m` and `Type2.m`:

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex < [self.tabBarController.viewControllers count] - 1) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex += 1;
    }
    else {
        // load nextData
        NSLog(@"nextData: %@", nextData);
        if (nextData == nil) {
            // essentially stop the next button from working
            return;
        }
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0U;
        [self.tabBarController setTitle:[nextData display_name]];
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[nextData loadTabs]];
    }
}
```

`loadTabs` is a method of the Data class (which is a Core Data NSManagedObject subclass with a category).

Inside `ParentData+Helpers.m` It looks like:

```
- (NSArray *)loadTabs {
    NSMutableArray *mut = [NSMutableArray new]; 
    for (SubData *d in self.datapoints) {
        if ([d.field_x isEqual:@YES]) {
            [mut addType1:d];
        else {
            [mut addType2:d];
    }
    return mut;
}
```

addType1 and addType2 are nearly identical in their fields, but have different implementations. They look like:

```
- (TypeVC *)addType1:(SubData *)data {
    TypeVC *vc = [[TypeVC alloc] init];
    vc.datapoint = data;
    return vc;
}
```

where TypeVC is either Type1 or Type2

So now I have a table view and each cell has an associated ParentData which has an array of SubData objects. When selected, it loads a UITabViewController with Type1 and Type2 VCs.

inside `TableVC.m`:

```
- (void)- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTabs" sender:self];
}
```

where toTabs leads to a UITabBarController in the storyboard.

In prepareForSegue:

```
UITabBarController presentedTabBarController = [segue destinationViewController];
[presentedTabBarController setTitle:self.selectedTitleName];
[presentedTabBarController setViewControllers:[self.selectedParentData loadTabs]];
```

So all that works fine.

So I run my app, get to the UITabBarController and the thing that should be there is. The first set of tabs has 2 tabs, so I hit next and it goes to the second one. I hit next, and it loads the next set of tabs and opens to the correct tab. I hit next, alls working good. I hit next four or five times, each time it works correctly. It doesnt matter if its Type1 or Type2, it works.

But then suddenly, I get to a specific one that has 2 tabs. It loads the first one (the one at index 0) and then I hit next. And suddenly I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xWHATEVER) at the line `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex += 1;`. I don't understand why this would happen.

Comment: Try turning on NSZombie. That should tell you which object it's trying to access that has been deallocated.

Comment: I can see now which object its trying to access, but I'm very confused as to why / what is trying to access it. Zombies tells me that its being sent a message, but I dont know what that message is. And it shouldn't be getting any messages. Ideas?